# How to use transformMatrix in CurvedText.js extension to Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I have used TransformMatrix for the activeObject for text and image but now I want to use it in the CurvedText.js

I have added it in the following way:

```
var _dimensionAffectingProps = fabric.Text.prototype._dimensionAffectingProps;
    _dimensionAffectingProps['radius']          = true;
    _dimensionAffectingProps['spacing']         = true;
    _dimensionAffectingProps['reverse']         = true;
    _dimensionAffectingProps['fill']            = true;
    _dimensionAffectingProps['textShadow']          = true;
    _dimensionAffectingProps['transformMatrix']         = true;

    var delegatedProperties = fabric.Group.prototype.delegatedProperties;
    delegatedProperties['backgroundColor']      = true;
    delegatedProperties['textBackgroundColor']  = true;
    delegatedProperties['textDecoration']       = true;
    delegatedProperties['stroke']               = true;
    delegatedProperties['strokeWidth']          = true;
    delegatedProperties['textShadow']           = true;
    delegatedProperties['transformMatrix']          = true;

    fabric.Curvedtext = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Text, fabric.Collection, /** @lends fabric.Curvedtext.prototype */ {

        type: 'curvedText',

        radius: 50,
                spacing: 15,
                reverse: false,
        bulge: false,
        curve:false,
        pintch:false,
        arch:false,
        wedge:false,
        roof:false,
        bridge:false,
        vally:false,
        transformMatrix:[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
```

and it is set to the every letter as:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.text.length; i++)
{
  this.letters.item(i).transformMatrix = [1,0.2, 0.2, 1, 0, 0]; 

/***OR*****/
this.letters.item(i).set( 'transformMatrix ',[1,0.2, 0.2, 1, 0, 0]);

}
```

but both of the ways are not affecting it.

Right now I am getting Roof Text which I have made by using fabric.curvedtext.js as:,
[image: Imperfect Roof text]
but I want this should be like :

[image: perfect Roof text]

can some one please help me out ......?

Comment: I have used activeObject.transformMatrix[1] ==  parseFloat(-0.2, 10); And it works for normal text but not for curved text why?            Kangax can you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to position letters based on formula, that is why you are getting output like this.

Checkout below link:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/e8hZy/

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
/// (c) Ken Fyrstenberg Nilsen, Abidas Software .com
/// License: CC-Attribute

var ctx = demo.getContext('2d'),
    font = '64px impact',
    w = demo.width,
    h = demo.height,
    curve,
    offsetY,
    bottom,
    textHeight,
    isTri = false,
    dltY,
    angleSteps = 180 / w,
    i = w,
    y,
    os = document.createElement('canvas'),
    octx = os.getContext('2d');

os.width = w;
os.height = h;

octx.font = font;
octx.textBaseline = 'top';
octx.textAlign = 'center';

function renderBridgeText() {

    curve = parseInt(iCurve.value, 10);
    offsetY = parseInt(iOffset.value, 10);
    textHeight = parseInt(iHeight.value, 10);
    bottom = parseInt(iBottom.value, 10);
    isTri = iTriangle.checked;

    vCurve.innerHTML = curve;
    vOffset.innerHTML = offsetY;
    vHeight.innerHTML = textHeight;
    vBottom.innerHTML = bottom;

    octx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);

    octx.fillText(iText.value.toUpperCase(), w * 0.5, 0);

    /// slide and dice
    i = w;
    dltY = curve / textHeight;
    y = 0;
    while (i--) {
        if (isTri) {
            y += dltY;
            if (i === (w * 0.5)|0) dltY = -dltY;
        } else {
            y = bottom - curve * Math.sin(i * angleSteps * Math.PI / 180);
        }
        ctx.drawImage(os, i, 0, 1, textHeight,
        i, h * 0.5 - offsetY / textHeight * y, 1, y);
    }
}

iCurve.onchange = iOffset.onchange = iHeight.onchange = iBottom.onchange = iText.onkeyup = iTriangle.onchange = renderBridgeText;

renderBridgeText()
}//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id=demo width=600 height=300></canvas>
<br>
    <span>Curve:</span>
<input id="iCurve" type="range" min=0 max=200 value=110>
<span id="vCurve">110</span>
    <br><span>OffsetY:</span>
<input id="iOffset" type="range" min=0 max=100 value=4>
<span id="vOffset">0</span>
    <br><span>Text height:</span>
<input id="iHeight" type="range" min=0 max=200 value=64>
<span id="vHeight">64</span>
    <br><span>Bottom:</span>
<input id="iBottom" type="range" min=0 max=200 value=200>
<span id="vBottom">200</span>
    <br><span>Triangle:</span>
    <input id="iTriangle" type="checkbox">
<br><span>Text:</span>
<input id="iText" type="text" value="BRIDGE TEXT">

</body>
```

You can modify your code based on this example.
It is drawing each pixel by scaling that portion according to the curve required.